# VPN affects DNS resolution on MacOS

Tags: macos, dns, minikube

I setup minikube on MacOS and as result there is a virtual intf created on the host machine as the following:

```
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether f2:18:98:52:ec:64 
    inet 192.168.64.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.64.255
    inet6 fe80::f018:98ff:fe52:ec64%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
    inet6 fdd5:e29:6049:e016:475:5258:18a3:3700 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 18 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: vmenet1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 20 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

On a minikube VM, I got an error when trying to pull a image when I run a VPN on the host machine:

```
$ docker run -it --net=container:$ID --pid=container:$ID --volumes-from=$ID alpine sh
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.19:59651->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout.
```

If I do a dig on host when the VPN is running, I got the following outputs showing dns with 192.168.64.1 fails.

```
(base) /etc $ dig registry-1.docker.io

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> registry-1.docker.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45428
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;registry-1.docker.io.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   52.205.127.201
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   34.237.244.67
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   52.55.124.246
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   52.72.252.48
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   34.203.135.183
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   52.202.132.224
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   54.86.228.181
registry-1.docker.io.   3591    IN  A   54.197.112.205

;; Query time: 347 msec
;; SERVER: 10.44.0.1#53(10.44.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 02 17:25:26 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 177

(base) /etc $ dig registry-1.docker.io @192.168.64.1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> registry-1.docker.io @192.168.64.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
(base) /etc $
```

If I stop the VPN and do a dig on the host, I got the following outputs showing dns with 192.168.64.1 success.

```
(base) /etc $ dig registry-1.docker.io

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> registry-1.docker.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39523
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;registry-1.docker.io.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   54.86.228.181
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   52.72.252.48
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   174.129.220.74
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   34.237.244.67
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   52.205.127.201
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   52.202.132.224
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   52.200.37.142
registry-1.docker.io.   600 IN  A   52.203.238.92

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
docker.io.      2920    IN  NS  ns-1168.awsdns-18.org.
docker.io.      2920    IN  NS  ns-513.awsdns-00.net.
docker.io.      2920    IN  NS  ns-1827.awsdns-36.co.uk.
docker.io.      2920    IN  NS  ns-421.awsdns-52.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-1168.awsdns-18.org.  143919  IN  A   205.251.196.144
ns-421.awsdns-52.com.   170410  IN  A   205.251.193.165
ns-513.awsdns-00.net.   132154  IN  A   205.251.194.1
ns-1168.awsdns-18.org.  143919  IN  AAAA    2600:9000:5304:9000::1
ns-1827.awsdns-36.co.uk. 171777 IN  AAAA    2600:9000:5307:2300::1
ns-421.awsdns-52.com.   172051  IN  AAAA    2600:9000:5301:a500::1
ns-513.awsdns-00.net.   132154  IN  AAAA    2600:9000:5302:100::1

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 202.96.134.133#53(202.96.134.133)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 02 17:25:56 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 466

(base) /etc $ dig registry-1.docker.io @192.168.64.1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> registry-1.docker.io @192.168.64.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21844
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;registry-1.docker.io.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   52.72.252.48
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   174.129.220.74
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   34.237.244.67
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   52.205.127.201
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   52.202.132.224
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   52.200.37.142
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   52.203.238.92
registry-1.docker.io.   752 IN  A   54.86.228.181

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.64.1#53(192.168.64.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 02 17:25:59 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 177
```

Why such behavior of DNS resolution with respect to VPN? How to make the DNS work when VPN is running?

Comment: This isn't about programming. You probably want [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a VPN all your traffic is routed via VPN tunnel and it can't reach 192.168.64.1 since the router in at the other VPN end doesn't know where this address is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> registry-1.docker.io @192.168.64.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This is an expected behavior so you need to set up a route to `192.168.64.0` so it doesn't end up in a VPN tunnel.

You can read how to do this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/756134/how-to-direct-ip-route-through-specific-interface-in-os-x) and [here](https://support.justaddpower.com/kb/article/320-adding-a-static-route-to-macos/).

Most simple one will look like: `route add -host 192.168.64.1 my.local.gateway.ip` which adds a route to `54.81.143.201` via specific gateway `my.local.gateway.ip`.

Comment: netstat -r shows there is a loopback route to 192.168.64.1. Actually I can ping 192.168.64.1 from host, which means it can be reached.